# how do i make a code that counts the number of workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, count

[my homework, already completed step 1](https://lms.uconn.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-591876-dt-content-rid-2212376_1/courses/1163-UCONN-MATH-3550-SEC002-10134/hw1.pdf)

How do I write code that counts the number of workbooks and worksheets I have? Whenever I put `.count` it says its not useable

This is what happens after I press f5:
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4jPR.png]

so i have

```
sub workbookworksheetcount()
   Debug.Print worksheet.count
end sub
```

Comment: Add the code to your question - I for one won't be going offsite and opening a PDF to help...

Comment: yeah i understand. im new to this site and programming in general

Comment: To start you off, an application may have one or more workbooks.  Each workbook may have one or more worksheets.  Unfortunately, MS doesn't provide the chart anymore.  I found it here http://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-object-model/

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub workbookworksheetcount()
 Debug.Print Application.Worksheets.Count
End Sub
```

Try this Code

Comment: Application.WorkSheets is referring to the active workbook only.  You have to loop through all workbooks to get the total worksheets count.